# Error in using NGramTokenize (lapply issue)

Tags: r, n-gram, rweka

I'm using the NGramTokenizer from the rWeka package. I believe i have installed everything correctly. I'm executing the following code:

```
Bigram_Tokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize= Bigram_Tokenizer()))
```

Error I receive is:

```
Error in lapply(x,f): argument "x" is missing with no default.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks again in advance.

Best

Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be executing Bigram_Tokenizer() in TermDocumentMatrix function instead of just passing it by reference. You need to just pass it withou executing:

```
Bigram_Tokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize= Bigram_Tokenizer))
```

Comment: what does min = 2 and max = 2 stands for ?